# How do I strip any characters out of the telephone field

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

How do I strip any characters that are not a number out of the telephone field, including spaces.  I need to have a string of numbers 0-9.  No () or spaces.

i have a maskedinput for telephone (999) 999-9999

```
Phone Number:         
<input id="phone" type="text" />   (999) 999-9999
```

i just need **9999999999**

i am using maskedinput plugin http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var str = "(999) 999-9999";

str = str.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

Removes anything that is not a digit `\D`.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/tylermwashburn/YsHjR/

```
var phonenum = "(123) 456-7890",
    notnum = /\D/g;

phonenum = phonenum.replace(notnum, '');

alert(phonenum);
```

This should form it nicely.

Comment: I didn't see his answer until after I posted it. But mine's better because it has a demo. :D

Comment: It's good to post a demo link, but please remember to include the solution as well so your answer isn't dependent on the uptime of another site. :o)

Comment: Psh. What are you talking about. That was always there and not added 5 seconds ago. xD