# Jquery maskedinput plugin remove 'oOlL' character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery maskedinput plugin and I wants to remove 'o' , 'O' , 'l' , 'L' character. 
I've searched a lot but could find any proper way to do this. 
I tried using **[How do I strip any characters out of the telephone field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227174/how-do-i-strip-any-characters-out-of-the-telephone-field)**
But no Luck.

I tried this one as well but still it's not working.
[jQuery(function($){
            $.mask.definitions['h']="[lLoO]";
        });](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227174/how-do-i-strip-any-characters-out-of-the-telephone-field)

Can anyone hep me here. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your placeholder with this regular expression.

```
$.mask.definitions['a'] = "[A-HJ-NQ-Za-np-z0-9]"
$("#input").mask("aaaaaa");
```

Comment: Thank you very much absolutely worked for me. Had to change somethings though.